# Newly burned Lubuntu DVD does not boot -- disc not detected by DVD drive

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, dvd, burning

I downloaded the Lubuntu ISO from the first link on [the lubuntu website](http://lubuntu.net/).

I burned a DVD with **CD Burner XP** in another PC, and at the target computer changed BIOS boot settings to boot from CD/DVD drive first.

At the target computer, there was an old [Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/8.04.0/) already installed.

The DVD does not get detected when I put the newly burned DVD into the DVD drive.

Where am I wrong? Is there something that I misunderstood, for example, Lubuntu is really an OS which can be installed on hard disk?

Comment: By that do you mean , that  Ubuntu 8 Hardy Heron is Installed ( Dual Boot). Also did you downloaded the link naming [Download lubuntu (Intel x86) desktop CD] .While burning a ISO image , slowest writing speed is preferred ( 4X) . Did you checked the Integrity of downloaded ISO image ( Like md5 sum etc) before writing to DVD.

Comment: I think you forgot to reboot.

Comment: @mikewhatever : he has rebooted!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to boot your Lubuntu DVD. Check your booting preferences. I have installed Lubuntu like this way only and it works fine. Or there can be some problem while booting. Did you directly burn your DVD from the ISO file or extracted it and then burned it contents?

If yes then you have to burn the disc from the ISO file because that ISO file contains the instructions for booting which will be absent if you extract first and then boot.